# Informix IDS: DB_LOCALE vs GL_COLLATE, GL_CTYPE

Tags: informix

I tried restarting an Informix IDS database after setting `DB_LOCALE` environment variable to `en_US.57372`.
But, when I tried running the query on sysmaster,

select tabname, site from informix.systables where tabname like '%GL_%';
it gives me

```
tabname   GL_COLLATE
site     en_US.819

tabname   GL_CTYPE
site     en_US.819
```

Now, the database instance is not starting because it complains of

```
Error 23197: Database locale information mismatch.
```

I didn't install the database server, but I am assuming it was installed with default collation. Should I be changing the `GL_COLLATE` and `GL_CTYPE` to `en_US.57372` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware — minefields!

In general, when you create a database, the setting of `DB_LOCALE` at the time controls the locale for the database.  The locale `en_US.57372` corresponds with `en_US.utf8`.  So, if the database is created when `DB_LOCALE` is set to `en_US.utf8`, you will see the information:

```
SELECT tabid, tabname, site FROM INFORMIX.SysTables WHERE tabname MATCHES '*GL_*';

90  | GL_COLLATE  |en_US.57372
91  | GL_CTYPE    |en_US.57372
```

If the database is created without DB_LOCALE being set, or with it set to `en_US.8859-1` or `en_US.0333` or `en_US.819`, then you'll see:

```
90  | GL_COLLATE  |en_US.819
91  | GL_CTYPE    |en_US.819
```

Once the database is created, you need to connect using a correct setting for `DB_LOCALE`; you can't change the database locale by restarting the server with a new environment setting.  You would have to recreate the database to allow the new setting to work.  If the `DB_LOCALE` setting used when connecting to the database doesn't match the setting used when the database was created, you run into the error you see.

The `sysmaster` database is special.  It can be accessed from any database, regardless of locale.  But the information is not necessarily easily understood unless your actual locale matches its locale — which is `en_US.8859-1` even if `DB_LOCALE` is set when bringing up the server.  You'd have to set `SERVER_LOCALE` (the other relevant environment variable is `CLIENT_LOCALE` — but it isn't a factor at the moment) to stand a chance of changing the locale for the `sysmaster` database, but I've not experimented with that.

Comment: Can case sensitivity be toggled on/off after a db is created?